# Why is the limit of this expression not zero?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {-7^n + 8^{n-2}\over 7^{n+1} + 8^{n+2}} = \frac {1}{4096}$$

I don’t understand why this is the limit. Since the denominator has an $8^{n+2}$, isn’t the limit supposed to be 0? When you have a quotient of polynomials, and the denominator has the greatest exponent, isn’t the limit supposed to be 0?

Any help is appreciated.

PS: The fraction is supposed to be the general term of a series, so L’Hôpital’s rule does not apply.

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $8^n$ or $8^{n-2}$ or $8^{n+2}$.

Comment: This isn't a quotient of polynomials, since the variable is the exponent.

Comment: @Chappers Okey, I'm stupid, didn't realise that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{-7^n + 8^{n-2}}{7^{n+1} + 8^{n+2}} =\frac{-(7/8)^n+8^{-2}}{7(7/8)^n+8^2}$$

Now as $-1<7/8<1,\lim_{n\to\infty}(7/8)^n=0$

Comment: Thanks, this explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
write
$$
{-7^n + 8^{n-2}\over 7^{n+1} + 8^{n+2}} =
{-\left(\frac78\right)^n + \frac 1{64} \over 7 \left(\frac78\right)^n + 64} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

As often it's shorter with *equivalents*: as $7^n=o(8^{n-2})$ since $7<8$,
$$-7^n+8^{n-2}\sim_{\infty}8^{n-2}$$
Similarly, $\,7^{n+1}+8^{n+2}\sim_{\infty}8^{n+2}$, hence:
$$\frac{-7^n+8^{n-2}}{7^{n+1}+8^{n+2}}\sim_{\infty}\frac{8^{n-2}}{8^{n+2}}=\frac 1{8^4}=\frac1{4096}.$$